# Kendo angular Grid checkbox select all feature

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I was referring below url to add the checkboxes in kendo grid.

[https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/#toc-select-all-feature][1]

i am using the Kendo grid as below

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="Student" [height]="700" [pageSize]="25" 
 [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [filterable]="true" 
[selectable]="{enabled: true, checkboxOnly: true}">
    <kendo-grid-column title="Resubmit" width="90">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           <button kendoButton class="k-button" (click)="reSubmit(dataItem.ID)"  [icon]="'redo'"></button> 
           <input type="checkbox (click)="reSubmit(dataItem.ID)" />
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column title="Default checkbox">
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```

But any how the checkboxes are not clickable. 
Can someone help here what is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```html
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="Student" [height]="700" [pageSize]="25" 
 [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [filterable]="true" 
[selectable]="true">
    <kendo-grid-column title="Resubmit" width="90">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
           <button kendoButton class="k-button" (click)="reSubmit(dataItem.ID)"  [icon]="'redo'"></button> 
           <input type="checkbox (click)="reSubmit(dataItem.ID)" />
      </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column title="Default checkbox">
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```

Above is the corrected code solved my issue.

Comment: Any idea to disable the `kendo-grid-checkbox-colum`?